# GSA feeds - metadata posted is ignored

Tags: metadata, google-search-appliance

We are posting "metadata-and-url" GSA feed for some PDFs which cannot be reached through normal crawling. Along with URL of the PDF, we also submit additional metadata. The feed completes successfully and the PDF gets added to the GSA index (available in index diagnostics and in results XML). But the metadata posted gets ignored and only whatever metadata GSA itself extracts by crawling the document (author etc) is considered.

We are well below the license limit (not even 50% reached).

The feed record looks like this:

```
<record lock="true" action="add" mimetype="application/pdf" crawl-once="true" url="<PDF URL HERE>">
        <metadata>
            <meta content="md1value" name="md1name"/>
            <meta content="md2value" name="md2name"/>
            ...
        </metadata>
</record>
```

The index diagnostics page shows this metadata for the PDF:

```
Metadata Name   Metadata Content            Metadata Content length
CreationDate    D:20110622112810-04'00'     23
ModDate         D:20110622112949-04'00'     23
Producer        PDF-XChange 4.0.165.0       75
```

So there is no entry for md1name and md2name. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the excerpt from Google documentation.

**Metadata Information** - the URL metadata information at crawl time. Entity Recognition added metadata is also shown. Take note that when there is a great amount of metadata information, **not all of it appears here**, even though all metadata is still indexed correctly.

Inorder to see all metadatas,fire search query(without proxystylesheet) with 
getfields=* and check the result xml.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I did that as well. Did not get the metadata posted. Also, we do not have more than 4-5 meta entries,  and they do appear for some documents sometimes.

Comment: If the feed is submitted properly without any errors (Content Sources> Feeds), It must reflect in the result xml. It looks like strange behaviour. Please raise support ticket with Google.

Answer (score 1):

You should try stripping all xml-attributes from the feed and only push the most relevant ones (for example, remove: lock=true, crawl-once=true). After feeds are succesfully processed (and thus you are seeing the records and its metadata in the Index Diagnostics), you could try adding the attributes. So try the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE gsafeed PUBLIC "-//Google//DTD GSA Feeds//EN" "gsafeed.dtd">
<gsafeed>
<header>
    <datasource>$datasource_name</datasource>
    <feedtype>metadata-and-url</feedtype>
</header>
<group>
    <record action="add" mimetype="text/pdf" url="{$URL}">
        <metadata>
            <meta name="{$name1}" content="{$content1}" />
            <meta name="{$name2}" content="{$content2}" />
        </metadata>
    </record>
</group>
</gsafeed>
```

Also be sure that your feed client posts the feed with the appropriate type (metadata-and-url). And I believe the mimetype of a PDF-file is "text/pdf" and not "application/pdf" (things like this often gives a nice headache).

Comment: You don't need to specify the MIME type if the GSA is going to crawl the content.